# Stretch svg path to fit content

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a bunch of weird viewbox svg icons that I would like to normalized to the same size. I would like to stretch it fit the box perserving the ratio. (icomoon.io has a tool for that).
I could normalize the viewBox and translate path to the correct coordinate, however still cannot figure out how to get the ratio of how much I should scale.

For example this this icon has a padding

[image]

I know the ratio is  = (BoxX - BoxY) / (boundryX - boundryY)
I saw some answers suggesting getBBox() but it says not a function.

How I parse:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
 const svg = parser.parseFromString(item.contents, 'image/svg+xml');
      if(!svg.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]) return
      const viewBox = svg.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].getAttribute('viewBox');
      const path = svg.getElementsByTagName('path')[0].getAttribute('d');
```

the svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<title>arrow</title>
<path d="M3.597 10.945q0-0.316 0.246-0.528 0.164-0.163 0.458-0.163 0.363 0 0.528 0.234l6.48 7.347v-13.534q0-0.292 0.205-0.498t0.486-0.206q0.293 0 0.498 0.206t0.206 0.498v13.534l6.48-7.347q0.212-0.234 0.528-0.234 0.293 0 0.458 0.163 0.234 0.212 0.234 0.528 0 0.293-0.163 0.457l-7.782 8.837-0.046 0.024q-0.047 0.047-0.071 0.047l-0.141 0.070h-0.058q-0.047 0.024-0.141 0.024t-0.164-0.024l-0.117-0.046h-0.012t-0.012-0.024q-0.046 0-0.105-0.047l-0.046-0.024q0-0.047-0.046-0.047 0-0.024-0.012-0.024h-0.012l-7.699-8.766q-0.163-0.164-0.175-0.457z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok. I had to delete my answer because I used pretty stupid method. Inside browser there is API from you can get sement list of coords. For node.js I found [this svg parser](https://github.com/hughsk/svg-path-parser). All you need is min/max coords and set result to viewBox.